# What is the best way to handle connections (e.g. to mysql server using MySQLdb) in python, needed by multiple nested functions?

Tags: python, connection, global-variables

When accessing a MySQL database on low level using python, I use the MySQLdb module.

I create a connection instance, then a cursor instance then I pass it to every function, that needs the cursor.

Sometimes I have many nested function calls, all desiring the mysql_cursor. **Would it hurt to initialise the connection as global variable**, so I can save me a parameter for each function, that needs the cursor?

I can deliver an example, if my explanation was insufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that database cursors are scarce resources, so passing them around can limit your scalability and cause management issues (e.g. which method is responsible for closing the connection)?

I'd recommend pooling connections and keeping them open for the shortest time possible.  Check out the connection, perform the database operation, map any results to objects or data structures, and close the connection.  Pass the object or data structure with results around rather than passing the cursor itself.  The cursor scope should be narrow.

Comment: I got your point. But what if there are many database interactions necessary, shall I open a new connection in every function, instead of passing it as an argument?

Comment: The object that knows about units of work and transactions ought to create the connection, commit or roll it back, and then close it when the use case is complete.  It should pass that connection in to the methods that require it.